# IMG pushing parent inner space down - Parent height set in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've having a problem with an img causing excess space at the bottom of its parent. The parents height is set using Jquery so I can only guess that somehow the img is causing a conflict.

Edit: I tested changing the size of the image and can see that the spacing below becomes smaller, which tells me that it is a problem with the natural size of the image (which is larger than how it is being displayed).

[image]

```js
$('div.column-holder').each(function() {
  var parent = $(this);
  var maxHeight = 0;
  parent.children().each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = $(this).height();
    }
  });
  parent.find("div.column, div.shadow").innerHeight(maxHeight);
});
```

```html
<div class="column-holder">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="shadow bg-white">
      <div class="bdr-top-blue"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column-holder">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="shadow bg-white">
      <div class="bdr-top-blue"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="shadow bg-white">
      <div class="bdr-top-blue"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <img src="img/img1.jpg" width="100%" alt="" /> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since images are inline elements by default, they often cause excess space in html. Tldr: give it a property of `display: block`. More on this [here](https://dev.to/christiankaindl/the-strange-img-gap-in-html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately adding display: block; hasn't helped in this scenario.